# Duplicate jpa entity to another table avoiding potential deletion because of foreign keys

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm stuck with one problem which is that
I have 3 Entities with relations (OneToMany) between them
I will simplify it without all annotations and fields

```
@Entity(name = "diet")
public class Diet 
    @Id
    private String id;

    private List<Meal> mealList = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<String> receiversIds;


@Entity(name = "meal")
public class Meal {
    @Id
    private String id;

  
    private List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();


@Entity(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    private String id;
```

So, the diet can be created including field receiversIds.
So if the receiver has assigned diet I want him to have that diet for good.
If creator of the diets wants to remove all diets he could do that.
But the receiver should has his diet even if the creator will remove whole structure.
I decided to duplicate the row and put it in another table just for the receiver.
Here is the deal, If I will create a new Entity for receiver just to make a relation between Diet and him, then deletion will affect that table too because of the foreign keys in all levels.
Should I actually duplicate all entities : diet, meal, product and map original one to the duplicate structure just to create new entity tree and save that as an another record?
Unless there is any other possibility to avoid deletion in few level relationship structure

Comment: You haven't shown a receiver, and removing all annotations, specifically the relationship ones, is less helpful. What does this mean "But the receiver should has his diet even if the creator will remove whole structure"? It isn't clear why you need to duplicate anything at all or why you'd go with that approach - if receiver has a reference to a diet, just dereference it (null it out, clear the list, what ever). What exactly are you looking to have - seems like you want a Diet to reference the original receiver(s?) always, but be able to dereference the relationship from the receiver side.

Comment: I don't want situation when receiver has null values under the Meal or Product included in assigned Diet after the possible deletion whole diet by creator.
That's why I can not allow to onDelete process because of foreign keys, whole structure would be removed. 
So I decided to copy db record and set id as a new value (in my case, generated automatically) I made copy constructor. 
But because of the nested structure lower entities are duplicating ids anyway and I can not set it to null/other id because hibernate won't allow me to do that.

Comment: I didn't show receiver because it comes from accessToken and maybe I don't need that whole entity in this ms. Maybe it could be stored only as table with id_receiver id_diet. 
I would like to copy whole structure including all nested Ids

Comment: Why would a null be included in data? Deletion is something you and your settings are doing, not a requirement of merging in changes. You need to outline your use case. A receiver has a diet all worked out.. then what? They make a change and what do you want to happen exactly. I'm guessing you need a diet to be immutable, such that any change to the graph is treated like an entirely new version and persisted as such, much like history data or auditing is done. YOU are causing deletion. If you don't want to allow a diet to be deleted, don't. Mark it as deleted (known as soft delete) instead.

Comment: If you are having problems with fk constraints - show the mappings and the actual details. There should be no issue with setting a FK to null unless you've marked the relationship as not-nullable and generated a not-null constraint on the column. But if the full diet is meant to be immutable, you probably need to clone the full graph, or find a good way to version each piece independently - you'll basically be reinventing history/auditing though. You can mark the version as part of the ID (composite id) if you want, so that the app can see and use multiple versions.

Comment: Let me try clarify it.

Comment: Let me try clarify it. Creator can create diet/meal/product in one request or separately. Which means all ids are generated automatically by hibernate. In diet there is a field (list of receivers ids). Creator should see all diets he made and he should has chance to remove them. Each receiver should get assigned diet whenever he want. It's permanent. If the creator remove diet with assigned receivers then, they will lose chance to get their diets. That's why I want to duplicate a records just in case. Without a list of receivers ids but in relation OneToOne

Comment: If I will add @onDelete annotations all nested and connected records would be deleted, right? So if creator would remove product in meal1 in diet1, then it will be removed from all places, including that cloned record,  unless I will replace all ids in product, meal, diet to lose all foreign keys with original record

Comment: OnDelete clears the graph when you delete the root- why would you delete the root or even add that annotation or cascade option?